# I am using Laravel in order to make a DBMS for a social network. I need it to make an app. can anyone tell me how? i cant find anything on google

Tags: php, social-networking

Using Laravel for PHP and DBMS. How do I make an app? (for social networking).
I have googled most of the things but I am really an Amateur and need help.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud, the guy/girl is a beginner and you cannot expect from him her to know the basics. It is one of those beginner questions which should not be closed just because the asker is a beginner. We were all there at some point.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad thank you for supporting me. :)

Comment: That is perfectly normal. Beginners should be welcome here and elitists should remember that they were once beginners as well. You cannot elaborate the question greatly if you lack the knowledge to do that. We, the good guys try to help you start things. But when you get some experience, we will expect you to ask very well-versed questions ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many kinds of apps, so before you start to work on your app, you need to carefully determine what exactly you need. You could write desktop apps for various operating systems, or native mobile apps, or hybrids, or a web application... You name it. Anyway, Laravel is the server-side and it should be as agnostic to the apps as possible. You need to create an API and handle the following things:

- CRUD for the database
- session (log in, log out, register, password change, user settings)
- logical API functions
- file transfer protocol usage
- push notification (if needed)

As per your requirements, you will need to implement the server-side API in Laravel, which is a PHP-based framework and use an RDBMS, which could be MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, or a NoSQL database, for instance MongoDB.

Before you implement any apps, you should have a proof-of-concept for the API. You should not invest too much time working out the details of the API, as when you are going to work on a real app, you will notice things to be changed anyway. The API should be accompanied by a playground for testing, maybe a very small app without design where you could send requests to the API. Or you can implement a WebSocket API to have a single, duplex connection. It is up to you.

As about how to write an API, there are [many tutorials](http://blog.mashape.com/list-of-40-tutorials-on-how-to-create-an-api/).

Comment: I am glad for all down-votes if they are paired with constructive criticism. Without knowing why my post is down-voted I can not determine what the problem is and will assume that there is no problem.